# Не работает JS файл в Bootstrap 3

Tags: bootstrap

Все работало,пока не переподключил скрипты, вернул затем все как было,но js bootstrap не работает
 скрипт расположен под jquery, одинаковых классов нет в чем еще может быть проблема?

```
    </body>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="slider/css/owl.carousel.css">

    <script 
     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" 
      type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="theme/bootstrap 3/js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"> 
    </script>


    </html>
```

подключаю в самом конце

Comment: Вы бы выложили код подключения скриптов. И посмотрите в консоли браузера нет ли ошибок

Comment: </body>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="slider/css/owl.carousel.css">
        
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="theme/bootstrap 3/js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      
        
</html>

Comment: а пробел `bootstrap 3/` так и должно быть?

Comment: Да, с пробелом так и должен быть, я говорил, что все работало, пока скрипты не подключал другие

Comment: а в консоли ошибки есть?

Comment: Да вот и console молчит

Comment: __пока скрипты не подключал другие__ а кэш сбрасывали у браузера, может предыдущие скрипты в памяти висят? еще посмотрите закладку "сеть. в инструментах разработчика, чтобы убедиться, что файлы скриптов вообще подтягиваются

Comment: кэш тоже чистил и не раз